# From Map<String, Set<Integer>> collect values from a Set<String> of keys

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to use map to map a set of keys into a Map of String to Set of Integer. Ideally I want to get all the value sets and collect them into a single set.

Lets say I have:

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> keyValueMap = new HashMap<>();
Set<String> keys = new HashSet<>();
Set<String> result = new HashSet<>();
```

I have tried:

```
result.addAll(keys.stream().map(key -> keyValueMap.get(key)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

This nets me an error saying addAll() is not applicable for the type Set>. I have tried replacing map() with flatMap() but I can't seem to get the syntax right if that is the solution.

What is the correct syntax to make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the type of `result` should be `Set<Integer>` instead of `Set<String>`.

---

With your snippet, you're attempting to invoke [`Set#addAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)) on a `Set<Integer>`, but the argument being passed is a `Set<List<Integer>>`, which doesn't compile.

To ameliorate your issue, one solution is to use `flatMap` instead of `map`:

```
result.addAll(keys.stream()
                  .flatMap(key -> keyValueMap.get(key).stream())
                  .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
```

A logically equivalent snippet is:

```
result.addAll(keys.stream()
                  .map(keyValueMap::get)
                  .flatMap(List::stream)
                  .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
```

---

Another solution would be to utilize [`Map#values`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#values()):

```
result.addAll(keyValueMap.values().stream()
                         .flatMap(List::stream)
                         .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
```

Comment: When you say ameliorate, do you mean solve? Or is there a more performant way to do this?

Comment: @TimB. Ameliorate, meaning to make something better. In this case, it refers to fixing your compiler error. And if I were you, I'd take advantage of `Map#keySet` and `Map#values`.

Comment: Do you have a link where I can read up on that? I am new to streams in java.

Comment: @TimB. Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) for `Map`. It has many methods that could potentially suit your use-case.

Comment: My use case was actually a lot more complicated than my question above, so I am not quite sure there is better way to take advantage of Map#keySet and Map#values, but I will take another read through the docs and see.

Comment: Last part of this. What about if the Map<String, List<Integer>>  doesn't actually contain some keys represented in the set of keys?

Comment: @TimB. If you use `Map#keySet`, then you're working with a view of the set of keys in the `Map`. This means that its contents will always reflect what's in the `Map`. Otherwise, if you're building a new `Set` from the keys of the `Map` at one point in time, then the contents of that `Set` won't be updated by modifications to the `Map`. It explains it more clearly in the documentation that I linked previously.

Comment: So I mean assume Set<String> keys is a set of genes. keyValueMap is a Map of genes to pathways. I want to collect all the pathways associated with genes in the query set of genes. In some cases, the set of genes has genes not represented in the map. Your amelioration breaks if keyValueMap.get(key) returns null.

Comment: If the `Set` contains a gene whose respective pathway isn't represented in the `Map`, then there's nothing that can be done unless it's first added to the `Map`. Would you rather it return an empty `List` if no mapping exists?

Comment: Assuming you're using Java 8, you can change `keyValueMap.get(key)` to `keyValueMap.getOrDefault(key, Collections.emptyList())`. If you're using one of the other solutions I listed, then you can change `keyValueMap::get` to `key -> keyValueMap.getOrDefault(key, Collections.emptyList())`, or simply add a call to `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` below the call to `Stream#map`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! The second solution was not compilable for me for some reason so I am just sticking with the first.

Comment: There is no need for the `addAll`. Just assign the result of the `collect` operation to `result`, e.g. `Set<Integer> result = keys.stream() .flatMap(key -> getOrDefault(key, Collections.emptyList()).stream()) .collect(Collectors.toSet());`